# How can I return promise from thunk middleware in react redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, promise, redux-thunk

Currently, I'm stuck on one problem that I can't solve.
I am using thunk middleware for creating expenses as shown below.

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "../../../../src/axios";

export const addExpense = createAsyncThunk(
    "expense/addExpense",
    async (expense) => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.post("/expense", expense);
            // console.log(res);
            return { expense: res.data.expense, errorMessage: "" };
        } catch (err) {
            // console.log(err);
            return { errorMessage: err.response.data.message, expense: null };
        }
    }
);
```

Extra Reducers file that I'm using for managing states

```
[addExpense.pending]: (state) => {
    state.creatingExpense = true;
},
[addExpense.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
    const { expense, errorMessage } = action.payload;
    state.creatingExpense = false;
    if (state.expense && state.currentMonth === expense.month)
        state.expense = [...state.expense, expense];
    else if (errorMessage !== "") state.error = errorMessage;
},
[addExpense.rejected]: (state, action) => {
    state.creatingExpense = false;
    state.error = action.error;
},
```

Now I'm calling addExpense function after filling form and on the onSubmit function in the file below

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(addExpense(form));
    const year = form.date.split("-")[0];
    const month = form.date.split("-")[1];
    // console.log(error, creatingExpense);
    // if (error) return alert(error);
    navigate(`/year/${year}/${months[month - 1]}`);
};
```

Now whenever I'm creating an expense, it's directly navigating me to the /year page without being fulfilled.
So how can I return a promise from so that I can use navigate like below

```
dispatch(addExpense(form)).then(() => {
    navigate(`/year/${year}/${months[month - 1]}`);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this, I am facing the same problem here.

Comment: Haven't found any solution yet☹